# How to copy a csv file contents and rewrite with additional array in the same file?

Tags: php, csv

I have a one line csv file as below

```
table1, table_name //This is handled by one script
```

I need to add another row as

```
table2, table_name //This is handled by another script
```

Now, I want to add the table2 values without overwriting the table1 values in a csv file. So currently I'm doing

```
//for table1 in the same csv
$file = fopen('rowsCopied.csv', 'w+');
fputcsv($file, $row_write);
fclose($file);

//for table2 in the same csv
$file = fopen('anotherrowsCopied.csv', 'r');
$filecopy = fgetcsv($file);
fputcsv($file, $filecopy);
fclose($file);
```

I don't know how to proceed. Can someone help?

Comment: So does this work? Or not??

Comment: no, am i doing it correctly?

Comment: Please describe to us the problem completely. Dont just say _Dont Work_ And dump code on us

Comment: Step 1) Read the manual! `w+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. `

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need to have only two rows in that csv, one for one table value and other for another one. I am trying to rewrite the file without adding anymore lines, appending will result increase the no. of entries. So if i coud get the original value which is already there, i could open that in write mode and write the original values also add the last value, so that I will only have two lines in my csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the CSV file in "a+" mode and not in "w+" mode and then either directly append the rows or append a newline character first and then the CSV rows you want to add.
Let me know if it helped

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need to have only two rows in that csv, one for one table value and other for another one. I am trying to rewrite the file without adding anymore lines, appending will result increase the no. of entries. So if i coud get the original value which is already there, i could open that in write mode and write the original values also add the last value, so that I will only have two lines in my csv.

Comment: appending will not create a new line, it will just append the existing one. Also, please be clear, i can not understand your problem. You want to rewrite the same CSVs with just one more entry without adding a new line? This could be called appending